# Hilbert spaces and subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Problem:
Let $H$ be Hilbert space, $M$ is a closed subspace of $H$ and $u$ in $B(H)$.
If $(u(x),y)=0$ for all $x,y$ in $M$, then $u=0$ on $M$.

Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.  Take $H = \Bbb R^2$, and
$
M = \{(t,0): t \in \Bbb R\}$, and
$u(x_1,x_2) = (0,x_1)$.

Comment: Hi.that is right.thanks

Answer (score 0):

If $M\neq H$, then consider any $z \in M^{\perp}\setminus\{0\}$ and any $w\in M\setminus\{0\}$, and define $u \in B(H)$ by
$$
u(x) := \langle x,w\rangle z
$$
Then $u(w) \neq 0$ and $\langle u(x),y\rangle = 0$ for all $x,y\in M$.

Comment: Hi.that is right.thanks